# creating a view in a postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that proccess some data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(x integer, y timestamp with time zone, z integer[])
      RETURNS SETOF typea AS

$BODY$
SELECT *
FROM func1($1,$2,$3) as a
WHERE ...


$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

How can I convert the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM func1($1,$2,$3) as a
WHERE ...
```

into a `VIEW` ?
The thing is that func1 needs the function A parameters...

What I have now is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(x integer, y timestamp with time zone, z integer[])
      RETURNS SETOF typea AS
$BODY$
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW   myView as (select * from  func1($1,$2,$3));
select * from myView ;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

and i get

> ERROR: relation "myView " does not exist

in the `select * from myView ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that Postgres functions are handled in two steps.  In the first step, the function is compiled.  In the second, it is executed.

If the view does not exist, then it is not created during the compilation stage.  However, the `select` will fail, because the view doesn't exist.

Creating a view in a function seems strange to me.  However, I can think of two work-arounds:

- Be sure the view exists *before* the function is created.
- Use dynamic SQL to access the view within the function.

Comment: This function generate some data, work on it then gives final result. What I want is to view the result before and after the function did it's work. The first step of the function is to generate the data so the second step needs to be saving it. and that is where i'm stuck. How would U suggest to do that?

Comment: I would suggest that you either save the results into a table or print them out.  A view doesn't seem like the right solution to this problem.  You might want to ask *another* question describing what you are really trying to accomplish, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: You said Dynamic sql can solve it. How would u do that?